# What is the Difference Between NCM and MBIM?

Tags: usb, protocols

Now i am working for NCM and MBIM Protocol.In My observation MBIM is Latest of NCM.I need to know the difference between the NCM and MBIM about the Performance Level,Packet Format,Speed and etc...Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

NCM is a standard which targets Ethernet capable devices in the USB layer. MBIM is a standard which targets Mobile Broadband Modems (e.g. 2G/3g/4G ones) in the USB layer. Regarding packet format, NCM will use 802.3 (i.e IP packets with Ethernet headers), while MBIM  will use raw IP packets (i.e. just IP packets without Ethernet headers).